# pandas DatetimeIndex to matplotlib x-ticks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas Dateframe with a date index looking like this:

```
Date
2020-09-03
2020-09-04
2020-09-07 
2020-09-08
```

The dates are missing a few entries, since its only data for weekdays.

The thing I want to do is: Plot the figure and set an x tick on every Monday of the week.

So far I've tried:

```
date_form = DateFormatter("%d. %b %Y")
ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO))
```

But it will start with 1970 and not with the actual date index.

Then I tried to:

```
mdates.set_epoch('First day of my data')
```

But this won't help since Saturday and Sunday is skipped in my original Index.

Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a line plot with one axis of *datetime* type,
the most natural solution is to use *plot_date*.

I created an example DataFrame like below:

```
            Amount
Date              
2020-08-24     210
2020-08-25     220
2020-08-26     240
2020-08-27     215
2020-08-28     243
...
```

*Date* (the index) is of *datetime* type.

The code to draw is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
ax.plot_date(df.index, df.Amount, linestyle='solid')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=0))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The picture I got is:

[image]

As you can see, there is absolutely no problem with *x* ticks and they
are just on Mondays, as you want.